# ¿Cómo asignar un valor repetitivo a un data frame?

Tags: r

Estoy aprendiendo sobre el mundo de la programación en R, poco a poco voy aprendiendo pero igual sigue siendo complicado.. y necesito de su ayuda.. 
Tengo un data frame en el que los datos (id) se repiten,

```
id   x   
401  1.3
419  1.5
453  1.6
419  1.1
401  0.9
453  0.8
456  1.2
401  1.5
401  1.8
453  1.9
457  2.3
```

entonces a estos datos quiero asignarle una nueva columna en el que también se repita los datos pero con otros valores, algo así

```
id   x    y
401  1.3  1
419  1.5  2
453  1.6  3
419  1.1  2
401  0.9  1
453  0.8  3
456  1.2  4
401  1.5  1
401  1.8  1
453  1.9  3
457  2.3  5
```

Intenté haciendo lo siguiente:

```
y<-c(1:length(unique(id)))
mod(df$id,y)
```

Pero no me funciona ya que la columna "y" sale desordenada... Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma muy sencilla es convertir la columna `id` en un `factor` y luego transformarla en numérica:

```
df$y <- as.numeric(factor(df$id))
df

    id   x y
1  401 1.3 1
2  419 1.5 2
3  453 1.6 3
4  419 1.1 2
5  401 0.9 1
6  453 0.8 3
7  456 1.2 4
8  401 1.5 1
9  401 1.8 1
10 453 1.9 3
11 457 2.3 5
```

El `factor` es un tipo de dato categórico, cada valor tiene un `id` numérico que arranca desde el 1 y una etiqueta o `label` que tiene el valor visible de cada `id`, haciendo `factor(df$id)` conseguimos que 401=1, 419=2, 453=3, 456=4, 457=5, al convertir este `factor` en un numérico, obtenemos los nuevos `id`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Patricio, era justo lo que quería... son cosas básicas y relativamente sencillas pero a veces olvido lo sencillo... Gracias!